# Expecations calculation question (regarding the autocovariance sequence of the square of a zero-mean stationary proces)

Tags: time-series, expected-value, covariance, moments

I have a zero-mean stationary (weak) process ${X_t}$ (meaning $\operatorname{cov}(X_t,X_{t+\tau})$ is a function of $|\tau|$ only for all $t$) and from it we get $Y_t$ such that $Y_t = X^2_t$ . In working out the auto-covariance sequence for $Y_t$ I get:

$$s_Y(\tau) = \operatorname{cov}(X^2_t,X^2_{t+\tau}) = E(X^2_tX^2_{t+\tau}) - E(X^2_t)E(X^2_{t+\tau}).$$

My lecturer then says that this is equal to:

$$E(X^2_t)E(X^2_{t+\tau}) + 2E^2(X_tX_{t+\tau}) - E(X^2_t)E(X^2_{t+\tau}).$$

For the life of me I cannot see how $E(X^2_tX^2_{t+\tau}) = E(X^2_t)E(X^2_{t+\tau}) + 2E^2(X_tX_{t+\tau})$ here but it's stated as if it's trivial (and so I'll apologise in advance if this is a really simple question)

Answer (score 5):

**Your lecturer is wrong,** as a simple counterexample will show.

Consider the process $(X_t\mid t\in\mathbb Z)$ where

$$(X_t) = (\ldots,-1,1,-1,1,\ldots) = ((-1)^t)$$

with probability $1/2$ and otherwise

$$(X_t) = (\ldots,1,-1,1,-1,\ldots) = (-(-1)^t).$$

Simple calculations (using nothing more than the definitions of expectation and variance) show $E(X_t)=0,$ $\operatorname{Var}(X_t)=1,$ and $\operatorname{Cov}(X_t,X_{t+\tau})=(-1)^\tau$ for all integers $t$ and $\tau,$ establishing that $(X_t)$ is second-order (weakly) stationary.

The remaining calculations are trivial, since $X^2_t = 1$ is a constant series and $X_tX_{t+\tau}=(-1)^\tau.$ The constancy of $(X^2_t)$ implies its covariance function must be $s_Y(\tau)=0.$  That indeed is what your formula produces, but the lecturer's formula (if indeed it was transcribed correctly) gives

$$\eqalign{
&E(X^2_t)E(X^2_{t+\tau}) + 2E^2(X_tX_{t+\tau}) - E(X^2_t)E(X^2_{t+\tau}) \\
&= E(1)E(1) + 2(E((-1)^\tau))^2-E(1)E(1) \\
&= 2 \ne 0.
}$$