# If the square of a time series is stationary, is the original time series stationary?

Tags: time-series, self-study, data-transformation, stationarity

I found a solution that stated that if the square of a time series is stationary, so is the original time series, and vice-versa.
However I don't seem able to prove it, anyone has an idea if this is true, and if it is how to derive it?

Comment: Have you tried starting from the definition of stationarity?

Comment: This is essentially the question that was addressed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/340426/expecations-calculation-question-regarding-the-autocovariance-sequence-of-the-s/351556#351556, which you can find by searching for [square stationary](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=stationary+square+score%3A2).

Answer (score 15):

That conjecture is false.  A simple counter-example is the deterministic time-series $X_t = (-1)^t$ over times $t \in \mathbb{Z}$.  This time series is not even mean stationary, but its square is strictly stationary.

Comment: How about positive numbers only?

Comment: interesting. Is it possible to deduce nonstationarity from a single realization? That time series looks nonstationary only on paper.

Comment: But $X_t = (-1)^t$ is stationary, isn't it? Its mean is $0$ and it's variance is constant through time.

Comment: @smci Well, taking your additional requirement that with only positive numbers into consideration converts square function from even function to one-to-one function. Stationary status has transition property under one to one functions. Under this assumptions, you claim is true in both ways, you can also say that a positive stationary function's square is also stationary.

Comment: @Firebug The mean isn't zero. The mean is $-1$ for odd $t$ and $1$ for even.

Comment: @Acccumulation It's zero through time.

Comment: @Firebug It appears that at least one of doesn't understand what the word "stationary" means.

Comment: @AutomaticHourglass: (I'm not the OP; it's not my "additional requirement". It just seemed common-sense based on the intent behind the OP's claim)

Comment: @Ben To complete the answer, what about the other way around? If the original time series is stationary, is the square stationary? Here, it seems to work.

Comment: @Firebug: The series doesn't meet the standard definitions of stationarity --- its mean oscillates from $-1$ to $1$.  Periodic signals like this are not generally considered to be even weakly stationary, notwithstanding that they "average out" over multiple time points.  One could perhaps formulate a weaker sense of "stationarity" that looks at this, but it would not be the standard meaning of the concept.

Comment: I admit I've been more exposed to this 'wide-sense' stationarity than the strict meaning you adopted in your answer. So I concede, as it's outside my area of expertise.